# How can I resolve the '_CastError' error when reading a timestamp from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read a timestamp from firestore with flutter. I'm getting the following error on the birthDate in the AppUser.fromJson factory method: "_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast)".

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class AppUser {
  Timestamp? birthDate;
  String? displayName;
  String? uid;
  List<String>? profileImages;
  bool? registrationComplete;
  String? intro;
  String? gender;
  late List<Uint8List> profileImageBytes;

  AppUser({
    this.birthDate,
    this.displayName,
    this.uid,
    this.profileImages,
    this.registrationComplete,
    this.intro,
    this.gender,
  });

  factory AppUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AppUser(
      birthDate: json['birth_date'] as Timestamp,
      displayName: json['display_name'] as String?,
      uid: json['user_uid'] as String?,
      profileImages: json['profile_images'] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["profile_images"].map((x) => x)),
      registrationComplete: json['registration_complete'] as bool?,
      intro: json['intro'] as String?,
      gender: json['gender'] as String?,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @jamesdlin That didn't work I got error: "_TypeError (type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String')". Here is the format in firestore if that helps: 1993-10-17T00:00:00.000000Z

Comment: And what is the stacktrace for that error?  Are you sure that is from the same line and is not some separate error?

Comment: @jamesdlin yes it's on the same line and the stack trace is null

Comment: The stack trace should never be null.  Exactly what do you observe?  Post the entire error message, including the stack trace.  The error you describe does not make sense; it indicates that you're passing a `Timestamp` object where a `String` is expected, but your original error message indicates that `json['birth_date']` is a `String`.

Comment: @jamesdlin The stack trace is definitely null. https://imgur.com/BLlB9P8 Also, I figured out the problem is data related. It appears I have a row of data that is a Timestamp instead of a string. That's why it broke both ways but with different rows of data. So your original answer is correct if data is timestamp saved as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart casts treat one object as a different type of object. They do not perform any conversions.

To convert a `String` to a `cloud_firestore` [`Timestamp`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html), you will need to parse it:

```dart
    return AppUser(
      birthDate: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.parse(json['birth_date'])),
      ...
    );
```